# There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv, pipenv-install

I’m trying to just run my python project that seems to work fine on my Mac (best in pycharm, not as good but can run in VSCode) and terrible on my raspberry pi in VSCode. Whenever I run a `pipenv shell` and then a `pipenv install` it just complains with this error:

```
Pipfile.lock (e9a11d) out of date, updating to (47943b)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 709, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 692, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1403, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches graphene-django>=3.0.0b1 (from -r /tmp/pipenvcczdc6ayrequirements/pipenv-eg1jqra7-constraints.txt (line 3))
Tried: 1.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.2, 2.3.2, 2.4.0, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.1, 2.8.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.2, 2.9.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.1, 2.10.0, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.10.1, 2.11.0, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.11.1, 2.12.0, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.1, 2.13.0, 2.13.0, 2.14.0, 2.14.0, 2.15.0, 2.15.0
Skipped pre-versions: 1.0.dev20160909000001, 1.0.dev20160910000001, 1.0.dev20160917000001, 1.0.dev20160919000001, 1.0.dev20160919000002, 1.0.dev20160919000003, 1.0.dev20160919000004, 1.0.dev20160920000001, 1.0.dev20160922000001, 2.0.dev2017072501, 2.0.dev2017072601, 2.0.dev2017073101, 2.0.dev2017073101, 2.0.dev2017083101, 2.0.dev2017083101, 2.1rc0, 2.1rc0, 2.1rc1, 2.1rc1, 3.0.0b1, 3.0.0b1, 3.0.0b2, 3.0.0b2, 3.0.0b3, 3.0.0b3, 3.0.0b4, 3.0.0b4, 3.0.0b5, 3.0.0b5, 3.0.0b6, 3.0.0b6, 3.0.0b7, 3.0.0b7
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  graphene-django (from -r /tmp/pipenvcczdc6ayrequirements/pipenv-eg1jqra7-constraints.txt (line 3))
  graphene-django>=3.0.0b1 (from django-graphql-jwt==0.3.2->-r /tmp/pipenvcczdc6ayrequirements/pipenv-eg1jqra7-constraints.txt (line 5))
```

I don’t see what’s incompatible after running a `pipenv graph` (after `pipenv install --skip-lock`) as it returns this:

```
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
  - Django [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.2.3]
    - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.3.4]
      - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 3.10.0.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.1]
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.2
  - Django [required: >=1.11, installed: 3.2.3]
    - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.3.4]
      - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 3.10.0.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.1]
  - graphene-django [required: >=3.0.0b1, installed: 3.0.0b7]
    - Django [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.2.3]
      - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.3.4]
        - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 3.10.0.0]
      - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
      - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.1]
    - graphene [required: >=3.0.0b5,<4, installed: 3.0b7]
      - aniso8601 [required: >=8,<9, installed: 8.1.1]
      - graphql-core [required: >=3.1.2,<4, installed: 3.1.5]
      - graphql-relay [required: >=3.0,<4, installed: 3.1.0]
        - graphql-core [required: >=3.1, installed: 3.1.5]
        - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7,<4, installed: 3.10.0.0]
    - graphql-core [required: >=3.1.0,<4, installed: 3.1.5]
    - promise [required: >=2.1, installed: 2.3]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
    - text-unidecode [required: Any, installed: 1.3]
  - PyJWT [required: >=2,<3, installed: 2.1.0]
Rx==1.6.1
singledispatch==3.6.1
  - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
```

It seems that every version is installed correctly version-wide, including the graphene-django that it complains about [required: >=3.0.0b1, installed: 3.0.0b7].

Why is this error happening?

`pip3 list` returns:

```
Package             Version
------------------- --------
aniso8601           8.1.1
asgiref             3.3.4
Django              3.2.3
django-cors-headers 3.7.0
django-graphql-jwt  0.3.2
graphene            3.0b7
graphene-django     3.0.0b7
graphql-core        3.1.5
graphql-relay       3.1.0
pip                 21.1.1
promise             2.3
PyJWT               2.1.0
pytz                2021.1
Rx                  1.6.1
setuptools          56.0.0
singledispatch      3.6.1
six                 1.16.0
sqlparse            0.4.1
text-unidecode      1.3
typing-extensions   3.10.0.0
wheel               0.36.2
```

The Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
django-graphql-jwt = "*"
pyjwt = "1.7.1"
django-cors-headers = "*"
graphene-django = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[dev-packages]
```

I’ve tried a ton of things to try to fix this any have no idea where to go from here. I wanted to deploy this python, graphql and react project on my raspberry pi, but I assume I can’t if I can’t even get it to run. I'm trying to run this on my raspberry pi (running raspbian), and it is the back-end python app where the issue lies.

Any help, anything would be very much appreciated. I’m a beginner with python.

Comment: If I remove django-graphql-jwt = "*" from my Pipfile then `pipenv install` and `python manage.py runserver` run successfully, but then I get this error so surely that module is required: `Could not import 'app.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql_jwt'.` - I thought the error states the issue is with graphene-django, not django-graphql-jwt

Comment: I resolved this issue by upgrading to `pipenv --version` **2022.1.8**

Comment: @Gibron This helped me after I spent an entire day solving it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You somehow managed to install beta versions (used the `--pre` flag before then deleted the option from Pipfile, for example or used pip directly in the virtual env).

Now, because `django-graphql-jwt` doesn't conform to semantic versioning, they decided to depend on a major version, pre-release in a patch release `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
.

Since the 0.3.1 version of `django-graphql-jtw` depends on [`>=2.5.1`](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/blob/dd08b8d54b9c102c6cdd2b39df5eb4acc258fbe3/setup.py#L40), your beta version will still match, but without the `--pre` flag locking will fail, because the highest non-beta version is 2.5.1. That is the conflict being shown (but the output isn't very clear).

The resolution that should solve the issue is:

```sh
pipenv uninstall django-graphql-jwt django-graphene graphene graphql
# followed by:
pipenv install 'django-graphql-jwt<0.3.2'
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you, and well done! How did you know django-graphql-jwt depends on a major version (>=2.5.1)? And what is the --pre flag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `graphene-django` only has version `2.15.0` according to PyPI https://pypi.org/project/graphene-django/. But for some reason in this [commit](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/commit/d50a533e26f1509828ef9fc804b195ebdfc1c04e#diff-60f61ab7a8d1910d86d9fda2261620314edcae5894d5aaa236b821c7256badd7%20asks%20for%20version%20%60%27graphene-django%3E=3.0.0b1%60) of the library `django-graphql-jwt` it asks for
a version `3.0.0b1`. Which I think is the issue that shows in your log:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches graphene-django>=3.0.0b1 (from -r /tmp/pipenvcczdc6ayrequirements/pipenv-eg1jqra7-constraints.txt (line 3))
```

Apparently in this [commit](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/commit/754b2f175eabac4531cd4a70171ad4a5cfad9432#diff-60f61ab7a8d1910d86d9fda2261620314edcae5894d5aaa236b821c7256badd7) the latest `graphene-django` version was still supported. So my guess is that maybe downgrading to:

```
django-graphql-jwt="0.3.1"
```

instead of `0.3.2` should solve the problem. And it this case you can report them the issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error as before I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Actually Pipenv doesn't have a smart enough dependency resolver. I ran into the similar issue and switched to [poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry). Poetry will resolve your dependencies to the latest versions that match the constraints and don't conflict with each other.
Poetry is also much faster than Pipenv and provides a better user experience.

```
# pyproject.toml

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=1.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "sample"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Sample"
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.7"

django = "*"
django-graphql-jwt = "*"
pyjwt = "1.7.1"
django-cors-headers = "*"
graphene-django = "*"
```

In shell:

```
$ poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.6

$ poetry lock
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (15.3s)

Writing lock file

$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 17 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing six (1.16.0)
  • Installing promise (2.3)
  • Installing rx (1.6.1)
  • Installing graphql-core (2.3.2)
  • Installing typing-extensions (3.10.0.0)
  • Installing aniso8601 (7.0.0)
  • Installing asgiref (3.3.4)
  • Installing graphql-relay (2.0.1)
  • Installing pytz (2021.1)
  • Installing django (3.2.3)
  • Installing graphene (2.1.8)
  • Installing singledispatch (3.6.2)
  • Installing text-unidecode (1.3)
  • Installing graphene-django (2.15.0)
  • Installing pyjwt (1.7.1)
  • Installing django-cors-headers (3.7.0)
  • Installing django-graphql-jwt (0.3.1)
```

Comment: looks interesting, although fails to install: running the command `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py | python -` encounters this syntax error: `  File "<stdin>", line 134
    def data_dir(version: Optional[str] = None) -> Path:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
curl: (23) Failed writing body (363 != 1369)`

Comment: You are probably using python 2. As I remember, poetry required at least python 3.6. Try the same command, but use `python3` instead.

Comment: That managed to get it installed, although still cannot resolve dependencies

Comment: @user8758206, what version of the poetry did you use? Just checked and it worked for me (updated the answer, see the exact versions here)

Comment: I did actually run it, but immediately with --pre  and it doesn't solve it, because the deps are broken upstream. I said that as a one possible cause of the beta versions showing up in the installed packages. Yes, poetry does give you an environment that works and if that's fine with you go with it. It doesn't do what you ask (install the latest published version of django-graphql-jwt) and that bit me often enough that I stay away from it. But it's hard to write a good package manager, especially with different philosophies of what is "right".

Comment: Star usually means any, not the latest. And poetry will give you the latest *working* environment. I can't say the same for pipenv.