# pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure; ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pipenv, pipenv-install

I ran into what seems to be a dependency conflict when trying to run `pipenv lock` but can't seem to figure out what is causing this:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project specifies a build backend of setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__ in pyproject.toml
```

I tried to debug using the suggested `pipenv install --skip-lock` and `pipenv graph` and wasn't able to spot any conflicts in the output below:

```
bleach==4.1.0
  - packaging [required: Any, installed: 21.3]
    - pyparsing [required: >=2.0.2,!=3.0.5, installed: 3.0.6]
  - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.16.0]
  - webencodings [required: Any, installed: 0.5.1]
bpython==0.21
  - curtsies [required: >=0.3.5, installed: 0.3.5]
    - blessings [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.7]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
    - cwcwidth [required: Any, installed: 0.1.4]
  - cwcwidth [required: Any, installed: 0.1.4]
  - greenlet [required: Any, installed: 1.1.1]
  - pygments [required: Any, installed: 2.10.0]
  - pyxdg [required: Any, installed: 0.27]
  - requests [required: Any, installed: 2.26.0]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2021.5.30]
    - charset-normalizer [required: ~=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.2]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.6]
coverage==5.5
django-environ==0.6.0
django-extensions==3.1.3
  - Django [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.2.7]
    - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.4.1]
      - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 4.0.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.2]
django-filter==2.4.0
  - Django [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.2.7]
    - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.4.1]
      - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 4.0.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.2]
django-nose==1.4.7
  - nose [required: >=1.2.1, installed: 1.3.7]
djangorestframework==3.12.4
  - django [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.2.7]
    - asgiref [required: >=3.3.2,<4, installed: 3.4.1]
      - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 4.0.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.4.2]
eventlet==0.31.1
  - dnspython [required: >=1.15.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.16.0]
  - greenlet [required: >=0.3, installed: 1.1.1]
  - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.16.0]
factory-boy==3.2.0
  - Faker [required: >=0.7.0, installed: 8.12.1]
    - python-dateutil [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.8.2]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
    - text-unidecode [required: ==1.3, installed: 1.3]
gunicorn==20.1.0
  - setuptools [required: >=3.0, installed: 59.4.0]
locust==2.2.1
  - ConfigArgParse [required: >=1.0, installed: 1.5.2]
  - flask [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.1]
    - click [required: >=7.1.2, installed: 8.0.1]
      - importlib-metadata [required: Any, installed: 4.8.2]
        - typing-extensions [required: >=3.6.4, installed: 4.0.0]
        - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.6.0]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=3.0, installed: 3.0.1]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
  - Flask-BasicAuth [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.0]
    - Flask [required: Any, installed: 2.0.1]
      - click [required: >=7.1.2, installed: 8.0.1]
        - importlib-metadata [required: Any, installed: 4.8.2]
          - typing-extensions [required: >=3.6.4, installed: 4.0.0]
          - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.6.0]
      - itsdangerous [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
      - Jinja2 [required: >=3.0, installed: 3.0.1]
        - MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
      - Werkzeug [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
  - Flask-Cors [required: >=3.0.10, installed: 3.0.10]
    - Flask [required: >=0.9, installed: 2.0.1]
      - click [required: >=7.1.2, installed: 8.0.1]
        - importlib-metadata [required: Any, installed: 4.8.2]
          - typing-extensions [required: >=3.6.4, installed: 4.0.0]
          - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.6.0]
      - itsdangerous [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
      - Jinja2 [required: >=3.0, installed: 3.0.1]
        - MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
      - Werkzeug [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.0.1]
    - Six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
  - gevent [required: >=20.9.0, installed: 21.8.0]
    - greenlet [required: >=1.1.0,<2.0, installed: 1.1.1]
    - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
    - zope.event [required: Any, installed: 4.5.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
    - zope.interface [required: Any, installed: 5.4.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
  - geventhttpclient [required: >=1.5.1, installed: 1.5.1]
    - brotli [required: Any, installed: 1.0.9]
    - certifi [required: Any, installed: 2021.5.30]
    - gevent [required: >=0.13, installed: 21.8.0]
      - greenlet [required: >=1.1.0,<2.0, installed: 1.1.1]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
      - zope.event [required: Any, installed: 4.5.0]
        - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
      - zope.interface [required: Any, installed: 5.4.0]
        - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
  - msgpack [required: >=0.6.2, installed: 1.0.2]
  - psutil [required: >=5.6.7, installed: 5.8.0]
  - pyzmq [required: >=22.2.1, installed: 22.2.1]
  - requests [required: >=2.9.1, installed: 2.26.0]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2021.5.30]
    - charset-normalizer [required: ~=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.2]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.6]
  - roundrobin [required: >=0.0.2, installed: 0.0.2]
  - Werkzeug [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.1]
openapi-spec-validator==0.3.1
  - jsonschema [required: Any, installed: 3.2.0]
    - attrs [required: >=17.4.0, installed: 21.2.0]
    - importlib-metadata [required: Any, installed: 4.8.2]
      - typing-extensions [required: >=3.6.4, installed: 4.0.0]
      - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.6.0]
    - pyrsistent [required: >=0.14.0, installed: 0.18.0]
    - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
    - six [required: >=1.11.0, installed: 1.16.0]
  - openapi-schema-validator [required: Any, installed: 0.1.5]
    - isodate [required: Any, installed: 0.6.0]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
    - jsonschema [required: >=3.0.0, installed: 3.2.0]
      - attrs [required: >=17.4.0, installed: 21.2.0]
      - importlib-metadata [required: Any, installed: 4.8.2]
        - typing-extensions [required: >=3.6.4, installed: 4.0.0]
        - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.6.0]
      - pyrsistent [required: >=0.14.0, installed: 0.18.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 59.4.0]
      - six [required: >=1.11.0, installed: 1.16.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
  - PyYAML [required: >=5.1, installed: 5.4.1]
  - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
parameterized==0.8.1
prance==0.21.8.0
  - chardet [required: >=3.0,<5.0, installed: 4.0.0]
  - requests [required: ~=2.25, installed: 2.26.0]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2021.5.30]
    - charset-normalizer [required: ~=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.2]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.6]
  - ruamel.yaml [required: ~=0.17.10, installed: 0.17.16]
    - ruamel.yaml.clib [required: >=0.1.2, installed: 0.2.6]
  - semver [required: ~=2.13, installed: 2.13.0]
  - six [required: ~=1.15, installed: 1.16.0]
psycopg2==2.9.1
pylint-fail-under==0.3.0
  - pylint [required: Any, installed: 2.11.1]
    - astroid [required: >=2.8.0,<2.9, installed: 2.8.5]
      - lazy-object-proxy [required: >=1.4.0, installed: 1.6.0]
      - setuptools [required: >=20.0, installed: 59.4.0]
      - typed-ast [required: >=1.4.0,<2.0, installed: 1.5.0]
      - typing-extensions [required: >=3.10, installed: 4.0.0]
      - wrapt [required: >=1.11,<1.14, installed: 1.13.3]
    - isort [required: >=4.2.5,<6, installed: 5.10.1]
    - mccabe [required: >=0.6,<0.7, installed: 0.6.1]
    - platformdirs [required: >=2.2.0, installed: 2.4.0]
    - toml [required: >=0.7.1, installed: 0.10.2]
    - typing-extensions [required: >=3.10.0, installed: 4.0.0]
```

This is my `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
asgiref = "==3.4.1"
attrs = "==21.2.0"
blessings = "==1.7"
bpython = "==0.21"
certifi = "==2021.5.30"
chardet = "==4.0.0"
charset-normalizer = "==2.0.4"
click = "==8.0.1"
coverage = "==5.5"
curtsies = "==0.3.5"
cwcwidth = "==0.1.4"
django-environ = "==0.6.0"
django-extensions = "==3.1.3"
django-filter = "==2.4.0"
django-nose = "==1.4.7"
djangorestframework = "==3.12.4"
dnspython = "==1.16.0"
eventlet = "==0.31.1"
factory-boy = "==3.2.0"
gevent = "*"
geventhttpclient = "==1.5.1"
greenlet = "==1.1.1"
gunicorn = "==20.1.0"
idna = "==3.2"
isodate = "==0.6.0"
itsdangerous = "==2.0.1"
jsonschema = "==3.2.0"
locust = "==2.2.1"
msgpack = "==1.0.2"
nose = "==1.3.7"
openapi-schema-validator = "==0.1.5"
openapi-spec-validator = "==0.3.1"
parameterized = "==0.8.1"
prance = "==0.21.8.0"
psutil = "==5.8.0"
psycopg2 = "==2.9.1"
pyrsistent = "==0.18.0"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.2"
pytz = "==2021.1"
pyxdg = "==0.27"
pyzmq = "==22.2.1"
requests = "==2.26.0"
roundrobin = "==0.0.2"
"ruamel.yaml" = "==0.17.16"
"ruamel.yaml.clib" = "==0.2.6"
semver = "==2.13.0"
six = "==1.16.0"
sqlparse = "==0.4.2"
text-unidecode = "==1.3"
urllib3 = "==1.26.6"
"zope.event" = "==4.5.0"
"zope.interface" = "==5.4.0"
Brotli = "==1.0.9"
ConfigArgParse = "==1.5.2"
Django = "==3.2.7"
Faker = "==8.12.1"
Flask = "==2.0.1"
Flask-BasicAuth = "==0.2.0"
Flask-Cors = "==3.0.10"
Jinja2 = "==3.0.1"
MarkupSafe = "==2.0.1"
Pygments = "==2.10.0"
PyYAML = "==5.4.1"
Werkzeug = "==2.0.1"
pylint = "*"
pylint-fail-under = "*"
bleach = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

and the output of `pip3 freeze`:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
astroid==2.8.5
attrs==21.2.0
bleach==4.1.0
blessings==1.7
bpython==0.21
Brotli==1.0.9
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==8.0.1
ConfigArgParse==1.5.2
coverage==5.5
curtsies==0.3.5
cwcwidth==0.1.4
Django==3.2.7
django-environ==0.6.0
django-extensions==3.1.3
django-filter==2.4.0
django-nose==1.4.7
djangorestframework==3.12.4
dnspython==1.16.0
eventlet==0.31.1
factory-boy==3.2.0
Faker==8.12.1
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-BasicAuth==0.2.0
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
gevent==21.8.0
geventhttpclient==1.5.1
greenlet==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.2
importlib-metadata==4.8.2
isodate==0.6.0
isort==5.10.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
locust==2.2.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mccabe==0.6.1
msgpack==1.0.2
nose==1.3.7
openapi-schema-validator==0.1.5
openapi-spec-validator==0.3.1
packaging==21.3
parameterized==0.8.1
platformdirs==2.4.0
prance==0.21.8.0
psutil==5.8.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
Pygments==2.10.0
pylint==2.11.1
pylint-fail-under==0.3.0
pyparsing==3.0.6
pyrsistent==0.18.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
pyxdg==0.27
PyYAML==5.4.1
pyzmq==22.2.1
requests==2.26.0
roundrobin==0.0.2
ruamel.yaml==0.17.16
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
semver==2.13.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
text-unidecode==1.3
toml==0.10.2
typed-ast==1.5.0
typing_extensions==4.0.0
urllib3==1.26.6
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1
wrapt==1.13.3
zipp==3.6.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

how can I resolve the above conflict ?

Comment: This seems to be related to this question, but the answers posted did not fix my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652324/there-are-incompatible-versions-in-the-resolved-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution to the problem but the following worked for me:
(ran after exiting the virtenv)

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv shell
pipenv install --skip-lock --verbose (ran verbose to check for anything fishy)
pipenv lock --pre
```